# how to hide/unhide view when taped on webview in page based application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

I want to hide/unhide grey colored view(Which has button) and it is on top of cream/biege colored webView - **please see attached pic**

[image: PageBased App]

I have used an page based application template available in xcode.

**Approach 1:Hide/unhide inside controller**

 i have tried to hide/unhide in same controller 
 but the problem is every time new instance of this controller created and bool values for hide/unhide are lost

**Approach 2:Protocol & Delegates**

 I have also tried to use delegate/protocol to maintain its status from its parent controller but it never gets inside if block -

  if ([self.delegateReadingToolbar........ block is never called.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if(touch)
{

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(webViewTouch,  location))
    {

        //do whatever
        NSLog(@"webView Touched");

        if (self.showReadingToolBar)
        {

            self.showReadingToolBar = NO; // approach 1
            self.viewReadingToolBar.hidden = NO;

            // approach 2
            if ([self.delegateReadingToolbar respondsToSelector:@selector(contentViewDidFinish:showStatus:)]) 
            { // this block is never called

                [self.delegateReadingToolbar contentViewDidFinish:self showStatus:NO];

            }


        }
        else
        {

            self.showReadingToolBar = YES;
            self.viewReadingToolBar.hidden = YES;
            [self.delegateReadingToolbar contentViewDidFinish:self showStatus:YES];

        }



    }
}

}
```

**For Approach 2 Coding:**

**ChildController.h**

```
@class ChildController;

@protocol ReadingToolbarShowDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)contentViewDidFinish:(contentView *)controller showStatus:(BOOL)show;

@end

@property (nonatomic,weak)id<ReadingToolbarShowDelegate>delegateReadingToolbar;
```

**ParentController.h**

```
#import "ChildController.h"

@interface ParentController :      UIViewController<UIPageViewControllerDataSource,UIPageViewControllerDelegate,ReadingToolbarShowDelegate>
```

**ParentController.m**

```
-(void)ChildControllerDidFinish:(contentView *)controller showStatus:(BOOL)show
{

   showReadingToolbar = show;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you alloc/init a new controller the previously set values will be gone. You are essentially creating a new object. I see a couple of different ways you may be able to do this.

1. Place your controllers inside a navigation controller and simply push the others on or off the stack. This way you don't have to instantiate a new object.
2. You could save the desired display configuration In an NSUserDefaults key/value pair. Whenever you need to create a new object of this type it looks up the value in NSUserDefault.

Comment: your option 1 is not viable in my case - as i have to deal with more then 1000 pages - and i have to keep it dynamic as well - it may grow up any number of pages.

Comment: Option no 2 - NSUserDefault is good but we can't overuse to make 1000 key/value pairs - do you know whats available limit for NSUserDefaults

Comment: Is there way i can achieve it Protocols - i am already using it in sample project but its not working when i move the same code to my final project

Comment: Do you have a master container that is around the whole time?

Comment: I have used NSUserDefaults but still desired results are not found